# Configuring third party service in my CompilerPass

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I'm using Symfony 2.7 and I want to configure some service by adding configurator to it. I follow instructions on http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/configurators.html, but I want to add my configurator to that service in my CompilerPass.
I wrote the following code:

```
$container->getDefinition('exercise_html_purifier.config.default')
    ->setConfigurator([
        $container->getDefinition('application.exercise_html_purifier.config_configurator')->getClass(),
        'configure'
    ]);
```

where `application.exercise_html_purifier.config_configurator` is `id` of my configurator service. This code works as expected, but of course it is also triggers php's warning:

> DEPRECATED - Non-static method Application\Service\ExerciseHTMLPurifier\Configurator\ConfigConfigurator::configure() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

because the `configure` method is not static in my case. I can't figure out, how to tell symfony to set non-static configurator callback.
I tried to set it like this:

```
$container->getDefinition('exercise_html_purifier.config.default')
    ->setConfigurator([
        $container->get('application.exercise_html_purifier.config_configurator'),
        'configure'
    ]);
```

but got this error:

> ContextErrorException in XmlDumper.php line 201:
>   Warning: DOMElement::setAttribute() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given

I even tried to use the following syntax:

```
$container->getDefinition('exercise_html_purifier.config.default')
    ->setConfigurator([
        '@application.exercise_html_purifier.config_configurator',
        'configure'
    ]);
```

but also got error

> FatalErrorException in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 2992:
>   Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting identifier (T_STRING)

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like your `$container->get('application.exercise_html_purifier.config_configurator')` returns something wrong and pass this something to the purifier. `DOMElement::setAttribute()` expects `attr_name` and `attr_value`, so var_dump it.

Comment: @Sergio Ivanuzzo $container->get('application.exercise_html_purifier.config_configurator') returns instance of my service as planned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've read the source of `\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Dumper\XmlDumper::addService()` and found that one of the solutions is to pass `Definition` instead of instance:

```
$container->getDefinition('exercise_html_purifier.config.default')
    ->setConfigurator([
        $container->getDefinition('application.exercise_html_purifier.config_configurator'),
        'configure'
    ]);
```